# Internet Explorer displays diacritics in Times New Roman, while Chrome, Mozilla do not

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am using Google API for the fonts on my website, it is great looking on Chrome, I have no problems, diacritics still use the fonts I want. On Mozilla, the same, but the fonts look quite bold. Not a big deal thought.

On Internet Explorer however, it looks fine, just like Chrome, no Mozilla bold, but it's a bigger issue: my diacritics display as Times New Roman. Is there any way to make them not do this? At least is there any way I could change this to Arial? I really need those to be the same font as the other text, because otherwise it looks weird and smaller.

[Internet Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkqL2.png)

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0TLm.png)

Comment: This doesn't sound like a coding problem but a font issue. Are you specifying a font stack, and what is the default font set in IE?

Comment: Screenshots of the issue are not enough; we need a [mcve] that can reproduce the problem. And if I may take a guess, I'd say Mozilla has precisely the same problem as IE, it's just chosen a different font for the offending characters.